# Backbone.js App Firing Requests Sporadically--i.e. No Request or Multiple Requests When Only One Should be Fired

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am relatively new to Backbone.js, but I thought I had the hang of it until now. I have a basic contact-management app going, but whenever I click the submit button for creating a new contact, it sometimes doesn't send a `POST` request at all, but sometimes Backbone.js sends two or more `POST` requests when I only intended to send one. A similar situation happens when I try to delete contacts by sending a `DELETE` request. Here is my stack:

**Front-End:**
JQuery
Underscore
Backbone
Require

**Back-End:**
Node
Express
Mongodb and Mongoose

I believe it is a Backbone/Front-End problem because when reading the requests sent with the Chrome Developer Tools network menu, I saw the multiple requests there. Below is what I believe is the relevant code in my app. If you want to see more, just request. I am quite perplexed by this problem, and can only hope that someone out there isn't. Thanks!

**editContact.js:** (View)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/editcontact.html',
  'models/contact'
], function($, _, Backbone, editContactTemplate, Contact){

  $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
      if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
          o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
      } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
      }
    });
    return o;
  };

  var EditContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.contactview',
    render: function (options) {
      var that = this;
      if (options.id) {
        that.contact = new Contact({id: options.id});
        that.contact.fetch({
          success: function (contact) {
            var template = _.template(editContactTemplate, {contact: contact});
            that.$el.html(template);
          }
        });
      } else {
        var template = _.template(editContactTemplate, {contact: null});
        this.$el.html(template);
      }
    },
    events: {
      'submit .edit-contact-form': 'saveContact',
      'click .delete': 'deleteContact'
    },
    saveContact: function (ev) {
      var contactDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
      var contact = new Contact();
      contact.save(contactDetails, {
        success: function (contact) {
          Backbone.history.navigate('contacts/' + contact.id, {trigger: true});
        }
      });
      return false;
    },
    deleteContact: function (ev) {
      this.contact.destroy({
        success: function () {
          $('.contactview').html('');
          Backbone.history.navigate('', {trigger: true});
        }
      });
      return false;
      }
  });

  return EditContactView;

});
```

**editContactTemplate.html:** (Template)

```
<form class="edit-contact-form">
  <legend><%= contact ? 'Edit' : 'Create' %> Contact</legend>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%= contact ? contact.get('firstname') : '' %>">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<%= contact ? contact.get('lastname') : '' %>">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="<%= contact ? contact.get('email') : '' %>">
  <label>Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="<%= contact ? contact.get('phonenumber') : '' %>">
  <hr>
  <button type="submit" class="btn"><%= contact ? 'Save' : 'Create' %></button>
  <% if (contact) { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= contact.id %>">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button>
  <% }; %>
</form>
```

**Contact.js:** (Model)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){

  var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/contacts'
  });

  return ContactModel;
});
```

**Router.js** (Router)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/allcontacts',
  'views/editcontact',
  'views/contact'
], function($, _, Backbone, AllContactsView, EditContactView, ContactView){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
    '': 'contacts',
    'newcontact': 'editContact',
    'edit/:id': 'editContact',
    'contacts/:id': 'viewContact'
    }
  });

  var initialize = function () {
    var router = new AppRouter();

    router.on('route:contacts', function() {
      var allContactsView = new AllContactsView();
      allContactsView.render();
    });
    router.on('route:editContact', function(id) {
      var allContactsView = new AllContactsView();
      allContactsView.render();
      var editContactView = new EditContactView();
      editContactView.render({id: id});
    });
    router.on('route:viewContact', function(id) {
      var allContactsView = new AllContactsView();
      allContactsView.render();
      var contactView = new ContactView();
      contactView.render({id: id});
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you instantiating EditContactView?  Is it possible that you're instantiating multiple views with the same "el" (as that would explain the multiples)? As for the missing requests, is it possible that you're instantiating EditContactView without a model sometimes?

Without more info it's hard to guess exactly what might be wrong, but here's a simple debugging idea: define a "fetch" method on your model, add a `debugger;` line to it, then invoke the Backbone fetch (`Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);`).  This way you can use Firebug/Chrome dev tools/etc. to pause and inspect things every time your model fetches.

Comment: Here: I'll post the router code as well while I try out your debugging suggestion. Can you explain in a bit more detail what you mean? I understand adding the `debugger;` line to the model inside a fetch method, but where should I put the `Backbone.Model.fetch.apply(this, arguments);`, and what exactly does it do?

Comment: You'd put it right after the debugger line, and what it does is essentially `super()` in other languages; in other words, it calls the parent's (in this case, Model's) fetch method, but with "this" (your sub-class of Model) as the "this".  By combining the two lines you keep all the fetch functionality that you'd normally inherit from Backbone.Model, but you still get to interject your debugger line.

Comment: (As a side note, this is actually a very useful pattern to learn with Backbone, as it lets your subclasses invoke their parent class's methods when they override them.  For instance, maybe your class A extends from class B, and class B has an initialize function.  You want A to have it's own initialize, but you also want to keep B's initialize; just do: `B.initialize.apply(this, arguments);` inside A's initialize, and you're set.)

Comment: Alright: Here is the code I used: `var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/contacts'
  fetch: function () {
   debugger;
   Backbone.Model.fetch.apply(this);
  }
 });` But it gave me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected identifier` error... Sorry if I am a total noob at this.

Comment: Oh shoot, I'm really sorry, I messed up the pattern and forgot `.prototype`.  It should have been . `Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this)` ... sorry for the confusion (and man I wish JS made that simpler).

Comment: ha, I agree. Javascript is great and awful at the same time. Unfortunately it still gives me the same error. Now that I think about it, my problem might be related to the first idea you had. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix it... Hopefully having the router code as well helps...

Comment: Ok, I think I might see the problem now.  You specify `el: '.contactview'` for your view, which means that every time you instantiate an `EditContactView` (or any other view with the same el), for instance because you navigate routes, you create a new view on that same element.  When that element triggers an event, all of those views respond to it.

Comment: There are several solutions to this, but the simple ones I can see are: A) wipe out the '.contactview' element and create a new one each time, or B) delete the view (via `view.remove()`) after you're done with it, or C) instead of making a new view every time, store the view somehow (eg. `this.$el.data('view', this)`) and then re-use it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion by implementing `this.$el.html('');` at the beginning of each view's render function. Unfortunately, I still seem to be getting duplicate requests, as creating one new contact actually created 7 new ones on 2 different ids...

Comment: `this.$el.html('');` clears out the *contents* of your element, but leaves the element (and any attached views) behind; try `this.$el.remove()` instead.

Comment: The short answer is: I can't write your app for you ;-)  The larger answer is that you probably want to do when you know you're done with the view, which generally will be when people navigate away.  If you wanted the view to "clean itself up", it could even have it register an event handler with the router, and then onRoute it could invoke it's own removal function.  That's just one thought, but there are many other possibilities ... I just can't provide them all :-)

Comment: For a different, more comprehensive approach, you may wish to see: https://paydirtapp.com/blog/backbone-in-practice-memory-management-and-event-bindings/

Comment: FIXED IT! Turns out that the closest I got to one of your suggestions was in fact option C. Up above in my router code, I was creating a new view object for every time I routed to the page. As a result, when I sent a click event, it would trigger the event in every one of the duplicated views. When I shifted all of the new view object statements outside of the `router.on` statements it only created one when the app was initialized. Thanks for all the help! I'm sorry if I was annoying in any way. I am still a noob, but your help taught me more.

Comment: No need to apologize at all; this is a place to learn :-)  I just ... you can't give everything in comments threads, and if you try they get really long and ugly, so I was trying to "help you help yourself" rather than doing everything in the comments.  Glad you arrived at a solution!

Comment: Sorry about the comment stream. Thanks for the help! You are quite kind.